# Loading data from staging table to main table in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

As of today, what is the most efficient way to load data from a staging table to main table in **oracle**.

Suppose I have my table as below

```
TABLE Persons
(
Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
HouseNumber int,
)
```

And below is my staging table

```
TABLE Persons_Staging
(
Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
HouseNumber varchar(255),
)
```

What I want to achieve is that on a daily basis , the new data from the staging table should be put into the main table **with some processing**.

For example, before loading the data into the firstname/lastname column, the data should be transformed in upper case/lower case somehow. Or may the date format in the date column be changed. (some basic transformations of data before loading into main table).

Shall I use procedures for this or there is any other tool available which I can use ?

Comment: well I prefer a procedure in order to control everything you need( specify the conditions, the order, the database name and other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best way to solve this kind of task is trigger.

You can just create trigger for Persons_Staging, it can be like this:

```
Create Or Replace Trigger Persons_Staging_Before_Insert
  Before Insert On Persons_Staging
  For Each Row

Declare
Begin
  Insert Into Persons
    (Id, Lastname, Firstname, Housenumber)
  Values
    (:New.Id,
     Upper(:New.Lastname),
     Upper(:New.Firstname),
     :New.Housenumber);
End;
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, pure SQL `INSERT` is the right way, i.e.

```
insert into persons 
  (id, lastname, firstname, housenumber)
select id, lastname, firstname, housenumber 
from persons_staging;
```

If you want to do some *processing*, do it while data resides in staging table, unless you can include those transformations into the above `INSERT` statement (such as `initcap` or `upper` you mentioned).

If you planned to use some kind of a PL/SQL, looping through all staging table rows, doing something with every row and then move it to the target table - well, that will probably be dead slow. Row-by-row processing is slow-by-slow.

If possible, do whatever you're doing in a way that it affects the whole data set, not piece by piece.

Also, try to avoid context switching (writing a SQL that calls PL/SQL, and repeats that many times). If you have a PL/SQL procedure which uses SQL statements, no problem - that works just fine.